# Create a preferred overload when multiple overloads make it past SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

```cpp
struct A { void a() { puts("a"); } };
struct B { void b() { puts("b"); } };
struct C : A, B {};

template <typename T> decltype(&T::a, (void)0) SFINAE(T t) { t.a(); }
template <typename T> decltype(&T::b, (void)0) SFINAE(T t) { t.b(); }

int foo()
{
    SFINAE(A{}); // works fine, calls a
    SFINAE(B{}); // works fine, calls b
    SFINAE(C{}); // compile error
}
```

The above code fails when calling SFINAE with a type that has `a` and `b`, thus making both templates valid resulting in an ambiguous call. How can I fix the above code to prefer the first overload in an ambiguous situation? So `SFINAE(C{})` should call `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disambiguate the calls by introducing a conversion:

```
template <typename T> decltype(&T::a, (void)0) impl(T t, int) { t.a(); }
template <typename T> decltype(&T::b, (void)0) impl(T t, unsigned) { t.b(); }

template <typename T> void SFINAE(T && t) { impl(std::forward<T>(t), 42); }
```

Passing `42` of type `int`, the first overload will be selected by the compiler as better match.

**<kbd>[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y1J7vNJC2r2AASXK)</kbd>**

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to express something like

1. has `a` and has not `b`
2. has `b` and has not `a`
3. has `a` and has `b`

e.g.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_a : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_a<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::a)>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_b : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_b<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::b)>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<has_a<T>::value && !has_b<T>::value> SFINAE(T t) { t.a(); }
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<has_b<T>::value && !has_a<T>::value> SFINAE(T t) { t.b(); }
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<has_a<T>::value && has_b<T>::value> SFINAE(T t) { t.a(); }
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jhIHsYgTsxaOQfRd)

As @mch [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987763/create-a-preferred-overload-when-multiple-overloads-make-it-past-sfinae/56988028#comment100510624_56988028), you can make your own conditional combination based on the actual situation.

Comment: You can combine the first and third `SFINAE` function to `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<has_a<T>::value> SFINAE(T t) { t.a(); }`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/c7M8CFVXyzt3LuFJ

Comment: @mch Nice idea. Anyway I'll keep this conditional logic in the answer, because it looks more clear then OP can make his own combination based on the actual situation.